# How to let python use negative numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been making a linear equation calculator and I'm wondering how to let python use negative numbers. Like int(), float() etc...

here is my code.

```
import time

print("Hello and welcome to the linear equation calculator.")

time.sleep(2)

print("Enter the first co-ordinate like this - (xx, yy): ")
coordnte1 = input()

print("Now enter the second co-ordinate like this, with the brackets, - (xx,yy): ")
coordnte2 = input()

print("Now the y-intercept: ")
yintrcpt = input()

ydif = coordnte2[1] - coordnte1[1]
xdif = coordnte2[0] - coodrnte1[0]
g = ydif / xdif

print("y = " + g + "x + " + yintrcpt)
```

And the problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dale/Documents/GitHub/new_python_rpi_experiments/linear.py", line 17,   in <module>
    ydif = coordnte2[1] - coordnte1[1]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I'm very new to Python, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you done to the vowels in your variable names?

Answer (score 3):

What your are reading from the input is a *string*, you need to extract the coordinates and convert them to *float*, for example:

```
print("Enter the first co-ordinate like this - (xx, yy): ")
s = input()
```

Now `s = "(34, 23)"` is a *string* and you need to process it (eliminate parens, comma, etc...):

```
coords = [float(coord) for coord in s.strip('()').split(',')]
```

Now coords is a list(array) of floats and you can do `coords[0]- coords[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with negative numbers. It's that `input()` gives you a text string. Python doesn't know how to subtract or do math with text strings, even if they happen to contain numeric characters.

You will need to write a function to convert a string of the form `(10,3)` to two numbers. I'll let you explore how to do that, but the `strip` and `split` methods of the string object may be useful to you, and you can use `int()` or `float()` on a string that contains only a numeric value to convert it to an integer or floating-point numeric variable. For example:     `int('123')` gives you the number `123`.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is also a good parser for data formatted as a Python literal.

Answer (score -1):

Try int:

```
ydif = int(coordnte2[1]) - int(coordnte1[1])
xdif = int(coordnte2[0]) - int(coodrnte1[0])
```

Comment: That would extract the first and second characters from the string, not the first and second numbers.

Answer (score -1):

```
ydif = float(coordnte2[1]) - float(coordnte1[1])
```

I think is your problem ...

Comment: Thanks. But I done that and now it says: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'

Comment: That would extract the first and second characters from the string, not the first and second numbers.

Answer (score -2):

Try using eval to convert the string to type, e.g.

```
coordnte1 = eval(coordnte1)
coordnte2 = eval(coordnte2)
```

You might want to put that in a try statement, because it will fail if the user inputs a string that can't be evaluated.

Comment: Using `eval` to convert a string to an int or float?

Comment: Why not?  It works perfectly, unless the user inputs something that throws a name error or syntax error.  I don't understand the down vote.

Comment: The program is designed to accept user-input, which would then be eval'd directly with this solution. If you let me eval anything I want, you're just setting yourself up for trouble. This may not be an issue if users can only run it on their own systems, but if the program is executed from anywhere else, with the appropriate permissions...

Comment: Fair point, assuming the intended users don't already have access to execute python scripts.  As long as that's kept in mind (and there are ways around it, such as removing all the alpha characters before evaluating), it's still a solution that works.